# ssh connect to host port 22: Connection refused

Tags: 18.04, ssh, docker, container

So I have a docker container and I want to connect to it with ssh from host(I know it's not indicated to ssh to a docker container, but I need to do it).

I have installed open ssh server on both container and host and the service is running on both. I also checked the ports for both docker and host and both are 22. I'm trying to connect to it as `root` and also as non privileged user. What can I do?

when running `ssh user@host -vvv` I'm getting this:

```
debug1: reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "host" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug2: connecting to host [host] port 22
debug1: connect to address host port 22: connection refused
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 18.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Usually, you don't ssh to a container. You can simply run `docker run -it my_container /bin/bash`.

Comment: But  I specifed that I know it's not recommended, but I need to do it with ssh. I know I can do it with docker run.

Comment: You should maybe ask about your initial problem, rather than your possible solution. See also: [What is the XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @pLumo `docker exec` might be more correct then `docker run` in this case to simulate connecting via ssh. `docker run` will start a new container instance while `docker exec` will connect to a running one. Unfortunately, though, it all depends on what the OP is trying to achieve to figure out what's the correct solution.

Comment: sure, it is `exec`, you're right...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default docker containers do not expose any ports.

To expose port to your host you need to add the option: `-p 22:22` to expose the port when you start running the container.

Example:

`docker run -p 22:22 $CONTAINER_NAME`

To permanatly expose a port in Docker you need to edit the `Dockerfile` for the container and rebuild it.

In the `Dockerfile` add the line.

`EXPOSE 22`

Not recommended to expose ssh port to a conatiner running in production.

Comment: This seems like a temporaty solution. Is there a way to do it permanently?

Comment: @TheoParaschiv That is the permanent solution. But it can depend on how you are starting it though. You must expose the port at runtime of the container. Unless you give complete information on what you are trying to do, or how you usually start a container this is the best and only correct way to do it

Comment: @A.Sha due to the edit regarding the `EXPOSE 22`, I must mention that the information is not correct. The `EXPOSE` command doesn't do anything at all. It is just for "documentation" purposes when users use a container so they know they need to expose a specific port with `-p`. More info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose.

Comment: Learn something everyday.:-) Thank You. Is there a actual way to permanently expose a port regardless of the launch command?

Comment: @A.Sha Nope, but you can use things like docker-compose to make it easier.